# T | null overload for useRef in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In [React type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b088c36b63e09f2e0d5548f59c304edb6d868e5d/types/react/index.d.ts#L1033-L1071), `useRef` has function overloading for `T|null` and `T`:

```
    function useRef<T>(initialValue: T): MutableRefObject<T>;
    // convenience overload for refs given as a ref prop as they typically start with a null value
    /**
     * ...
     *
     * Usage note: if you need the result of useRef to be directly mutable, include `| null` in the type
     * of the generic argument.
     *
     * ...
     */
    function useRef<T>(initialValue: T|null): RefObject<T>;
```

If I declare `useRef` with `<T|null>`, it uses first `useRef` that returns `MutableRefObject<T>` and when declare with `<T>`, it uses second one.

Why does this function overloading work like this?

When declaring with `T|null`, it use  function, and on declaring with `T`, it uses `<T|null>` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Typing React UseRef Hook](https://claritydev.net/blog/typescript-typing-react-useref-hook) for more details.